# Unable to upload Marlin 2.0 to Melzi 2.0 board

Tags: marlin, firmware, arduino, linux, melzi

I need to set the `HOME_POS` manually since it isn't printing in the center of the bed. But whenever I try to upload it to the Melzi 2.0 board I get an `out of sync` error.

I am using Arduino IDE on Manjaro Linux, I was able to upload Marlin to the board on Windows 10 but I have since removed that OS.
I have the correct settings for the board: Sanguino Atmega 1280 or 1280P (16mhz)

Here is what I have tried to get me this far:

- Running Arduino IDE as root (administrator) which fixed the
  `permission denied` error
- Changing the Board and the processor settings
- Uploading a fresh Marlin firmware with no changes
- **Uploading a simple program to my Arduino UNO which worked**
- Changing USB Ports (USB 3.0, USB 2.0)
- Changing the Baud Rate from 115200 to 57600

Here is the (verbose) error message

```
Arduino: 1.8.12 (Linux), Board: "Sanguino, ATmega1284 or ATmega1284P (16 MHz)"

Sketch uses 107854 bytes (82%) of program storage space. Maximum is 130048 bytes.
Global variables use 4054 bytes (24%) of dynamic memory, leaving 12330 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 16384 bytes.
/root/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17/bin/avrdude -C/root/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega1284p -carduino -P/dev/ttyUSB0 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:/tmp/arduino_build_963029/Marlin.ino.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/root/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/root/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyUSB0
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x73
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x74
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x61
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x72
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x74
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x0a
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x65
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x63
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x68
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x6f

avrdude done.  Thank you.

An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

Comment: have you tried installing via ISP pins?

Comment: So it was already running Marlin (uploaded from Win10)? You could have used [`M206`](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M206:_Offset_axes) to change the offsets instead of uploading a completely new firmware. On topic, this is a very common and generic error message, a troubleshooting answer can be found [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/18/52058).

Comment: Your board might be using the old bootloader which needs a 57600 baud rate for uploading instead of the default 115200. You'd need to modify that in the respective boards.txt

Comment: @towe I tried that it did not work ( I added it to the question now to help narrow it down)

Comment: That's odd. Enable "Show verbose output during: ... upload" in your IDEs settings please. That should give you the avrdude line the IDE uses to try to upload to the board.

Comment: I found a suggestion on the Arduino stackexchange that you remove any shields or anything connecting digital pins 0 and 1. The error you're getting is a connection error and could mean any of a thousand things. Can you do as @towe suggested and enable verbose output?

Comment: @towe there you go :)

Comment: @towe i needed to change it in the serial monitor as well thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay thanks to @towe for helping me I figured it out.  my Baud Rate was set to 115200 but my board is using the old bootloader so it needed to be 57600.  I Changed my boards.txt file to that but the verbose console printed:
`Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200` turns out you need to change it in the serial monitor as well (the little magnifying glass in the top corner of the IDE)
after that everything worked great thanks for all the help!